# Would this approach will work as an Agile development project?

Tags: scrum, agile

I will start working on a software development project, currently the project is the initiation phase to divide into phases and select the product develop approach. This is my first time leading this kind of project, so I am planning in using an adaptive approach. Since I will present the PMP exam this month I am really into its procedures and guides, and now it is also focusing in Agile approach. My pasts project were always traditional approach, with predefined requirements and waterfall life cycle.

My question is, as I mentioned for the development phase I will use an agile approach, using iterations to develop the final product iteratively, do I need to use a framework, e.i. Scrum, or can I only use a "generic" iterative life cycle as the image below.
This is because I am not really familiar with any agile framework, in the future I would like to become an Scrum Master but for now I think using an Scrum framework is not the best idea due to lack of expertise.
PMs with SW development expertise, I need your help. :) Also if you have any tips or real life advice is also welcomed

**Edit: Adding more information:**

As I mentioned the project is still in the initiation phase.
So far the sponsor and myself are creating the project charter, define key deliverables, milestones, overall risks and stakeholders, objectives and acceptance criteria
Once is approved we will start the initial planning which will divide the project into phases for the different modules the application will have, and for then for the first phase plan its iterations and high level requirements. Since it and internal project our final customer will be internal to our team.

So I was planning that for example: Module 1

- Requirement 1
- Requirement 2
- Requirement 3...

Based on this high level requirements create scope statement and WBS.

So for each iteration, prioritize each requirement and the project team to design, develop, test and transition to production.

And continue iteratively until the final module is completed. And work the same way for the next modules, maybe work in parallel if possible, and at the end put together all the modules and transition to production.

Does this make sense from an Agile perspective? What would you change?
I know this sound as Scrum but I don't want to stick to this framework, to avoid doing the daily meetings, use a product owner, Scrum Master.

Thanks in advance!

[image: Agile life cycle]

Comment: You can do anything that works for your team, organization, and project. Why would you think you need to use a specific framework such as Scrum?

Comment: I think you need to revise the question for it to be suitable - as-is, it is too broad.  You don't 'need' to do anything - except design processes that work for your team personalities, workflows, and management needs.  None of those criteria were outlined in your question, yet

Comment: @ToddA.Jacobs Scrum was just an example. I was referring to any agile framework

Comment: @NewAlexandria I added more info and rephrase my question :)

Comment: Would you like to know if you can wrap agile inside traditional process (the answer is "no", but it's a very long no), if you can/should iterate within waterfall or is there another "what should I do question" here. It still feels a bit broad.

Comment: This question is too broad to answer. Why don't you try starting and come back when you face real problems. Perhaps you could focus a question on the blockers that prevent you from starting.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way to answer this question is to validate your approach against the Agile values.

**Responding to change over following a plan**

Does your approach allow you to respond quickly and with minimal cost to change? The change may be to the requirements, may be a result of technical uncertainty, or may be due to other factors.

Will the milestones and defined deliverables help you respond to change, or will they restrict and discourage change from happening?

**Customer collaboration over contract negotiation**

Does your approach allow you to regularly receive feedback from your customers and does it allow you time to respond to and incorporate that feedback?

**Working product over comprehensive documentation**

Will you be measuring progress by regularly delivering a working product to production or will you be relying on progress measured against a plan?

**Individuals and interactions over processes and tools**

Will your approach allow the development teams to adapt as they go along? Will conversations between people involved in the project be seen as more valuable than following the plan and other documents?

Answer (score 1):

Obviously all of the methods we now call "Agile" were developed from scratch by the team(s) involved, so of course your team can do so! The key phrase, though, is your *team*. This is what is meant by "self-organizing teams" in one of the Manifesto principles. Gather everyone in a room, walk through the Agile Manifesto, and facilitate creation of the team processes by the team. I was doing this before the Manifesto was written, and it is very effective if you facilitate well. But it takes time. Most teams I facilitated spent a couple of full days at it, and had to meet an extra couple of hours each week for a month or two to iron out snags. Still, that is my preferred approach to Agile, even through I wrote my own framework.

Adopting a framework offers at least two advantages: that's faster than creating your own--I taught Kanban to a high school robotics team in a couple of hours--and the parts have been tested together already in multiple teams. If you go that route, as a certified organizational change manager (and PMP/PMI-ACP), I caution you to try it "as-is" at first, until you see how the parts work together, and then you can start tailoring. (This is also the recommendation of both PMI's *Agile Guide* and the *Standard for Change Management* from my CM association.)

For what it's worth, my [Full Stack Scrum](http://fullstackscrum.net/) framework is free and open source, written with detailed instructions for do-it-yourselfers (and to your objection, it doesn't use Scrum Masters). But again, you don't need it! I would just trust your team.